# re-upload an image using ng-file-upload after increasing its brightness

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, ng-file-upload

I have a button "add photo" which upload images using ng-file-upload but after uploading I have created a method which changes the brightness of the image and save the image in a dataUrl. Now, The problem is overwriting the already existed image in upload folder. How to overwrite it?

```
 //Function for uploading photos using ng-file-upload

$scope.uploadPhotos = function(photos, errFiles) {

    var total_photos;
    $scope.house_images = [];
    $scope.photos = photos;

    $scope.errFiles = errFiles;
    angular.forEach(photos, function(photo) {
        console.log("photo====>",photo);
        $scope.img_to_canvas();
        photo.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: '/api/v1/flatmate/upload-images',
            data: { 'photo': photo }

        });

        photo.upload.then(function(response) {

            $scope.house_images.push(response.data[0]);

            $timeout(function() {
                photo.result = response.data[0];

            });
        }, function(response) {
            if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function(evt) {


            photo.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *
                evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });

    });
    console.log("images", $scope.house_images);
    console.log($scope.photos);
};


$scope.brightness = function(slider_model){

    var slider = slider_model;
    var image = document.getElementById('image');

    var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    context.drawImage(image,x,y);
    console.log(context);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(x,y,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
    console.log(data);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i+= 4) {
        data[i] += 5; //RED
        data[i + 1] += 5; //GREEN
        data[i + 2] += 5; //BLUE

    }

    console.log(data);

    context.putImageData(imageData, x, y); //draws up the image.

    data = null;
    imageData = null;
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();//image saved in dataUrl variable.

    // console.log("dataUrl", dataUrl);
    document.getElementById('image').src = dataUrl;

}
```

Comment: Why not delete the existing file and save the latest file ?

Comment: It will work too but can you show me some code for it.

Comment: You can convert the dataUrl to a file and upload it. `var brighterImageFile = upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataurl, name); Upload.upload({..., file: brighterImageFile, ...})`